# Positioning image in layer-list for Android Splash Screen

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen, layer-list

I'm trying to center an image in the top third of my splash screen.
I'd also like it to be at most 2/3rds as wide as the screen.

Right now my image is at the top of the screen, with a 60dp margin from the top, and spanning the entire width.

My app supports Android v4.4 to v9.0, and I'm testing on two v5.0 and v8.0 devices.

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <bitmap
      android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
      android:tileMode="disabled"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
  </item>
  <item
    android:top="60dp"
    android:left="60dp"
    android:right="60dp">
    <bitmap
      android:src="@drawable/logo"
      android:tileMode="disabled"
      android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

the top margin seems to have worked:

```
android:top="60dp"
```

but not:

```
android:left="60dp"
android:right="60dp"
```

Top seems to have worked, but the image is taking up the width of the screen so I can't tell if center_horizontal is.

```
android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
```

Any advice?